# Why mongoDb is slower than MySql in deleting documents?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I am doing some tests about databases performance. I am tried to delete the information stored into database.

I've noticed as MySql is faster than MongoDb for this type of operation.

Here the results:

- MySql time (in seconds): 163.724
- MondoDb time (in seconds): 221.150

Queries used:

MySql: 
     `DELETE FROM table`

MongoDb: `db.collection.remove({})`

In you opinion, why is this happening?

Structure of the document in mongoDB (version 3.2):

- > { "_id" : ObjectId("56a967615390f47f25798c97"), "user_id" : "1",
  >   "follower_id:" : "11" }

Structure of row in MySQL:

- > id=1     user_id=1     follower_id=11

Operating System used:

- > OS X El Capitan; 2,5Ghz Intel Core i7; 16GB RAM

Comment: That is a minimal difference (33%) which can have multiple causes: IO, internal structure, some overhead, the current collection you are deleting. So no way to tell.

Comment: give me some detailed information on the structure of the document, and the corresponding row in sql with which you are comparing the document.... The version of mongodb being used and the operating system used.... I may be able to do a detailed investigation in my spare time....

Comment: For that kind of deletion use `db.collection.drop()`. It will be instantaneous!

Comment: No, I need to keep the collection in my case.